# python 3.6 put number is str

Tags: python

```
def binary(n):  
    if n>0:   
        return binary(n//2)*10 + (n%2)
    else:    
        return 0
```

The answer is 10000000 but it have to be "10000000". How can I put str on the answer?

Comment: `def binary(128)` is invalid.

Comment: @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ He suspect he meant `n`. `128` was probably the argument he was trying to pass into the function.

Comment: str(binary(n//2)*10 + (n%2))

Comment: def binary(n):  
    if n>0:   
        return binary(n//2)*10 + (n%2)

    else:    
        return 0

Comment: str(binary(n//2)*10 + (n%2)) is not working

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I will suggest that you use nested/inner functions as shown below to solve you problem. This allows you to compute the result using integers, and then convert the result to a string, or any other type, before returning it.

```
def binary(n):
    def inner(m):  
        if m>0:   
            return inner(m//2)*10 + (m%2)
        else:    
            return 0
    return str(inner(n))
```

Alternatively you can cast n to the correct type whenever you use it. This is, in my opinion, a horrible to solve the problem, but it should still do the trick.

```
def binary(n):
    if int(n) > 0:
        return str(int(binary(n//2))*10 + n%2)
    else:
        return "0"
```

Comment: @Jonas I believe you are confused. The _return type_ and output type must match. But the input type can be any type. Also, Python really doesn't have types the way you are presenting them. So that's probably confusing the OP more than it it's helping them.

Comment: Yes, now it's ok. Why do you still use `int(n)`, though? Instead of just `n`? If you think that that's necessary, then you should do it in your first solution, too.

Answer (score 1):

In python, to change the type of anything, the only thing you have to do is wrap that in `str()`, `int()`, `float()`... or whatever type you want to change it to.

more details: http://usingpython.com/python-casting/

edit: sorry, didn't realize the recursive problem, still, I don't see why you can't just change the type after the function returns, seems the easiest thing to do.

if you insist though:

```
def binary(n):  
  if int(n)>0:   
    return str( int(binary(str(int(n)//2)))*10 + (int(n)%2))

  else:    
    return str(0)
```

Comment: that is why I added the edit, maybe I'm misunderstanding something, but I don't see the need to directly return a str, when you can just change it after calling the function

Comment: @ChristianDean Why/how would the arguments of subsequent calls be casted to a string?

Comment: @ChristianDean Huh? How would a returned result become the argument? That just doesn't happen.

Comment: @StefanPochmann that is how recursive functions, like the one in the question, work: you call the function from inside the same function.

Comment: @Naira But not with the result as the argument! (In this case, I mean... of course you can write recursive functions that do call themselves once and then again with the result of that call as the argument... but that has nothing to do with what's here).

Answer (score 0):

The problem with simply wrapping your return in a cast to `str()`, is that the subsequent calls to `binary()` will be affected, not just the top-level call. After the deepest recursive call to binary has finished, it will return its result - which is a string - to the next deepest recursive call to the expression:

```
binary(n // 2) * 10 + (n % 2)
```

But since the return value is a string, it fails when used in the expression.

The obvious solution is to simply cast the return value of `binary()` to a string from wherever it's being called. However, if for some reason you cannot do this, you can make a second function nested under `binary`, call this function *inside* of `binary()`, and cast its result to a string:

```
>>> def binary(n):
    def _binary(n):
        if n > 0:   
            return _binary(n // 2) * 10 + (n % 2)

        else:    
            return 0
    return str(_binary(n))

>>> binary(128)
'10000000'
>>> binary(64)
'1000000'
>>> binary(32)
'100000'
>>> binary(16)
'10000'
>>> binary(8)
'1000'
>>> binary(4)
'100'
>>> binary(2)
'10'
>>>
```

As @StefanPochmann pointed out, this method would also work:

```
def binary(n): 
    return binary(n // 2) + str(n % 2) if n > 1 else str(n)
```

Comment: I'd say the real obvious solution to the *"the return value is a string"* problem is to turn it into an int :-P

Comment: @StefanPochmann Ha. Yea, I guess you could do that to. At the time, that solution didn't occur to me as I was occupied doing something else. Man I'm having a long day.

Comment: Though I'd really just get rid of the silliness of converting to another int altogether, and just work with strings: `def binary(n): return binary(n // 2) + str(n % 2) if n > 1 else str(n)`.

Comment: @StefanPochmann Thanks. I guess if you don't mind I'll add that to my answer. I think my brain is fried for today :P